# How to call methods on an ASMX service client

Tags: c#, web-services, rest

I wrote a web service with a WebMethod called `GetLastVehicle()` and deployed it on IIS. When I go to the address in browser I can see and work with the method.

When I add the web service as service reference to my project and want to use it, I can't see my method. Instead there are `GetLastVehicleRequest`, `GetLastVehicleRequestBody`, `GetLastVehicleResponse` and `GetLastVehicleResponseBody`.

This is the service method:

```
[WebMethod]
public Vehicle GetLastVehicle()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    Vehicle lastVehicle = new Vehicle();
    lastVehicle.ID = rnd.Next();
    lastVehicle.StartTimeStr = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    lastVehicle.Direction = Convert.ToBoolean(rnd.Next(0, 1));
    lastVehicle.VehicleLength = float.Parse(rnd.Next(2, 6).ToString());
    lastVehicle.GrossWeight = float.Parse(rnd.Next(1200,12000).ToString());
    lastVehicle.Velocity = float.Parse(rnd.Next(50, 140).ToString());
    lastVehicle.WheelBase = float.Parse(rnd.Next().ToString());
    lastVehicle.AxlesCount = rnd.Next(2, 9);
    List<Axle> lastVehicleAxles = new List<Axle>();
    for (int i = 0; i < lastVehicle.AxlesCount; i++)
    {
        Axle axle = new Axle();
        axle.Weight = rnd.Next(500, Convert.ToInt32(lastVehicle.GrossWeight / lastVehicle.AxlesCount));
        if (i == 0)
            axle.Distance = 0;
        else
            axle.Distance = rnd.Next(1, Convert.ToInt32(lastVehicle.VehicleLength / lastVehicle.AxlesCount) > 1 ? Convert.ToInt32(lastVehicle.VehicleLength / lastVehicle.AxlesCount) : 1);
        lastVehicleAxles.Add(axle);
    }
    lastVehicle.Axles = lastVehicleAxles;
    return lastVehicle;
}
```

How can I call it from my client?

Comment: Can you post your method declaration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to instantiate the proxy and call methods on that:

```
var client = new YourServiceClient(); 
GetLastVehicleResponse getLastVehicleResponse = client.GetLastVehicle();
```

Anyway you shouldn't be writing new services in ASMX Web Services. Courtesy of [John Saunders](https://stackoverflow.com/users/76337/john-saunders):

> ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the ASMX Forum on MSDN.

Comment: I just simulating a device that hasn't been arrived to us yet. by the way, when i use your code `var client = new WimWebService(); ` i get an error which tells that 'WimDataLogger.WimWebService' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'

Comment: That's because the client is called `WimDataLogger.WimWebService.WimDataLogger.WimWebServiceClient`, or whatever namespace you generated the client in (like `ServiceReference1.WimWebServiceClient`).